# Eclipse plugin development plugin requires second update site for installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I'm developing a plugin in eclipse and when you try to add the plugin to a brand new CDT installation it fails with following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Sloeber 4.0.0.201611052308 (io.sloeber.feature.feature.group 4.0.0.201611052308)
  Missing requirement: Ui 4.0.0.201611052308 (io.sloeber.ui 4.0.0.201611052308) requires 'package org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.oscilloscope.multichannel 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Sloeber 4.0.0.201611052308 (io.sloeber.feature.feature.group 4.0.0.201611052308)
    To: io.sloeber.ui [4.0.0.201611052308]
```

I know I need the update site
http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/snapshot
as this one contains a plugin my plugin is dependent upon.

If I add the link to the "software installation sites" the plugin install fine.
However I do not want users to have to add this link manually before they can install the plugin.
To try to fix the problem, I have added the nebula url to the category.xml of my update site in "repository properties" "additional Repositories" and to my feature.xml in information "sites to visit" but to no avail.

So my question is: How can I add links to other update sites so the plugin can be installed in one go?

Comment: did you solve the problem ?

Comment: No. I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add these extra update sites as features just like you did with your own plugin. This is what it looks like now in my update site project.
[image]

The code changes can be seen [here](https://github.com/wimjongman/arduino-eclipse-plugin/commit/f18181b29ff905008fe976a191608f0accad8c94)